# PHP: Why is this forced mime download adding 2 extra empty lines?

Tags: php, mime

I have a PHP script I wrote to create a .txt tab delimited file. I need to have this forced downloaded to the web browser. It does all this, but when I compare the file to the source the forced downloaded on contain two extra blank lines. Here is the code:

```
// Force download of the tab del .txt file to the web browser:

    header('Content-Type: application/download');
    header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=$tab_del_file");
    header("Content-Length: " . filesize($tab_del_file));

    $fp = fopen($tab_del_file, "r");
    fpassthru($fp);
    fclose($fp);
```

Linux Shell Command to compare the two files and show there are extra blank lines:
     $ diff example.txt /tmp/example.txt
    25a26,27

> I sftp'ed the downloaded example.txt to the /tmp directory so I could then do the diff on the server. Why are two blank lines being added to the downloaded version and what is the fix? Thanks!

Comment: do you have a closing `?>` tag in your php file?

Comment: i'm not a profi in PHP but i think that `$ diff example.txt tmp/example.txt 25a26,27 > >` is a wrong syntax

Comment: @hek2mgl. Thanks! I thought you were asking because if I didn't have a ?> it might be causing the problem. But I see now, it was the actual cause of this problem.

Comment: @AlexRuhl That's not PHP. That's the [`diff`](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?diff) command. OP used it to demonstrate that there are two additional new lines in the output.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out, I edited mine to explain I was using Linux shell. Sorry, I made the assumption that others working in PHP also work in a Linux platform.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the php code itself looks ok and does not produce that new lines, this can have only one reason. You have a closing `?>` tag and extra new lines at the end of your file:

```
?>
<--- empty line
<--- empty line
```

Note the content outside the php tags will not be parsed by PHP and just forwarded to the browser.

Solution: remove the closing `?>` tag or the extra new lines. I usually prefer just not using the `?>`

---

Btw, I should mention that this:

```
$fp = fopen($tab_del_file, "r");
fpassthru($fp);
fclose($fp);
```

can be simplified by

```
readfile($tab_del_file);
```

Comment: Thanks also for the readfile example. I changed the code and this also works!

Answer (score 1):

You most likely have an extra blank line after the closing `?>`, which is being echoed with the data. The closing `?>` is always optional at the end of a PHP file. Leaving it out is a good practice to prevent this sort of problem.

Comment: I do have a ?> at the end. I removed it, and this has fixed the problem. This has been helpful. I learned two things. The ?> is optional and when doing a MIME forced download like that don't have anything in the PHP code after last line of code. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Actually this is problem due to position of php closing Tag.. `?>`.

Basically the PHP closing tag on a PHP document `?>` is optional to the PHP parser. So if it is used in your script and you leave any whitespace after `?>` then it can cause unwanted error or output. I believe In your case also you would have done the same mistake.

So for this reason, PHP script should OMIT the closing Tag and instead you should use a comment block to mark the end of script.

Here is small example:

**INCORRECT:**

```
<?php

echo "Hello World!";

?>
```

**CORRECT:**

```
<?php

echo "Hello World!";

/* End of file myfile.php */
/* Location: ./system/modules/mymodule/myfile.php */
```

I Hope this helps you..!!

Comment: Thanks! That was also helpful!