# PHP fopen create a blank line automatically

Tags: php, fopen

Platform: Windows 10 & IIS, PHP 5.6

```
$base_dir = dirname(__DIR__);
$export_dir = 'export/';
if (!file_exists($export_dir)) {
    mkdir($export_dir, 0777, true);
}
$date = date_create(date());
$file_name = date_format($date,"Ymd").".txt";
if (file_exists($export_dir.$file_name)) {
    unlink($export_dir . $file_name);
}
$file = fopen($export_dir . $file_name, "w");
fclose($file);
```

The above code seems perfect with BLANK file output, however, when open the blank file, it contains a BLANK line inside and file size is not 0 kb.

I also tried "wt" or "wb" but output is the same.

What can I do to make sure create the .txt file is 0 kb?

Comment: Try to repeat the line `$file = fopen($export_dir . $file_name, "w");
fclose($file);` twice, you will see two blank lines!

Comment: You never put or write any data

Comment: *What can I do to make sure create the .txt file is 0 kb?* `touch('file.txt')` Why 0777?

Comment: The name file and folder have a size too ! . Try with small length name and folder inside that directory file

Comment: Try to create a new blank text file in Windows. It is 0 kb okay?

Comment: Please read this article.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16372678/php-why-is-this-forced-mime-download-adding-2-extra-empty-lines?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa